# Update a table from another table using triggers

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I am new using Triggers in Oracle SQL and I have a simple question.
I have 3 tables:

```
Table 1 COURSES
-IDCourse (Primary Key)
-Name
-SpaceAvaible

Table 2 STUDENTS
-IDStudent (Primary Key)
-lastName
-Name

Table 3 REGISTER
-IdRegister (Primary Key)
-Date
-IDCourse FOREIGN KEY
-IDStudent FOREIGN KEY
```

My question is how to make a trigger that updates the information of SpaceAvaible in COURSES when someone inserts a new data in REGISTER.
I tried but I'm stuck. :c

Comment: Can you share what have already tried as a minimal and reproducible example ?

Comment: Your basic design and assumption is flawed on several points.  First, the concept of 'space available' pre-supposes an indication of 'max seats'.  I don't see that anywhere in your design.  Second, keeping 'space available' is itself problematic, in that it is always possible to miss a change that would be reflected in that number - even with your trigger.  The basic rule here is never store a value that can be calculated at run time.  Your COURSES table should have a column for 'max_seats', and when you want to know 'available', calculate from what you have in REGISTER.

Answer (score 0):

I presume something like this; this *presumes* that `courses` table is already populated, and that `spaceavailable` isn't empty. How and where does it get its value, I have no idea - I just think that - if someone registers for that course - there's one space less available.

```
create or replace trigger trg_aiu_reg
  after insert or update on register
  for each row
begin
  update courses set
    spaceavailable = spaceavailable - 1
    where idcourse = :new.idcourse;
end;
/
```